# How to limit task executions in Camunda (without external synchronization)

Tags: camunda

I have a Camunda delegate which is supposed to send mails. We want to restrict the parallel executions of tasks so that the mail server is not flooded with too many messages.

Is there any (easy) possibility to restrict that task only to, say, 25 concurrent executions without resorting to Camunda-external synchronization (which is possible but complicated)?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the service task async in the modeler, the camunda jobexecutor will execute the delegate with a managed thread pool, so you will have a maximum of the definied executor threads sending mails. Could already be a solution for your problem.

Comment: well but it is not possible to specify a custom thread pool for a given task?

Comment: Not sure. A custom batch would an option, check the camunda-bpm-custom-batch extension